# UIAudioPickerController for iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod

Not sure what to call this, but I'd like to offer a way for users to pick and control their music from within my app. I've seen a few apps that offer an "iPod" button that appears to bring up the iPod app. Is this a built in control like the UIImagePickerController or have they simply duplicated all the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the MediaPlayer framework. In particular, you're talking about the [MPMediaPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing in [Couch to 5k](http://felttip.com/c25k/) is inserting a UIView with a toolbar, labels, and an image view. The toolbar has the standard buttons for controlling the iPod music player. Then I'm using `MPMusicPlayerController` to control the iPod music playback.

Here's some sample code to get the iPod music player and what's playing:

```
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
item = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
```

And then I register for NSNotification using the code provided in Apple's documentation on `MPMusicPlayerController`.